# Finding statistics, such as the mean, of all entries in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, statistics

I have a CSV file with 160 rows and 245 columns. It represents different pixels on a screen and each one takes a value. I want to calculate the mean over all the pixels/entries but can only find documentation on each row or column. How can I find the mean of the entire file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You juste have to load your dataframe with `pandas`, transform it into a `numpy.array` and then call `np.array.mean()`.

example

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_dataframe.csv', sep=';', decimal=',').to_numpy()
mean = df.mean()
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the .to_numpy() on the end :)